# Button size with respect to button's text in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a buttons that gets its caption with respect to locale. The problem is that the words are too long for my button in some languages. The question is, how can i change button's size so that it's width would be not less than text's width?

Comment: It depends on the sorounding layout properties how your button will align and grab space or not.

Comment: How is this Java? Vaadin also just produces HTML and CSS output, right? Well, if you're familiar with CSS, look at `min-width`.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. But it fixes simply by calling button.setWidth(null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to just call `vaadinButton.setSizeUndefined()` which will work as `width : auto;` as change in caption will get reflected to the width of the button in this case.

NOTE : After reviewing the comment of [`Henri Kerola`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270910/henri-kerola) stated below I must agree with the point that by default vaadin set the size undefined for button. So, if you does not specify the width it will be undefined by default.

Comment: This is the default size for a button in Vaadin.

Comment: It's part of the general component API and not all components in Vaadin are by default undefined sized.